# POST seems more sensitive than other memory test software

Tags: memory

During POST, my computer gives me beeps indicating a memory problem.
The beeps occur within a few seconds of pushing the power button.
The beeps are followed by nearly two minutes of logo during which the keyboard is unresponsive.
When it finally boots, everything seems ok.
When I try to verify with a memory-testing program,
it gives a clean bill even after several hours.

What is going on?

I was under the impression that POST was much less sensitive than memory testing programs.
Is that impression correct?

I suppose I will end up cracking the case and fiddling with my RAM.
Cracking the case is something I approach with fear and trepidation.
Before I do so, I'd like to understand the information available.
In particular, I'd like an explanation for the discrepancy between POST and memory-testing software.

Comment: Provide specific information.  So we can do our own research.  If your getting a error code indicating a memory problem then you have a memory problem.  Until this information is provided we cannot answer the question with facts only idle speculation.

Comment: I'm not sure how much of this is motherboard and how much BIOS: K9N SLI Platinum A7250NMS Ver. 1.30 08/02/06  I usually get two beeps and then three.  I have 4 GB of memory.

Comment: Your using MemTestx86 to test your memory correct?

Comment: Yes.  That is what I am using.

Comment: I would also update your firmware.  Its about 6 versions out of date.

Comment: Your description of the beep codes does not make sense...http://forum-en.msi.com/faq/article/bios-beep-codes.  I can tell you its not going to be the "RAM" error code based on 2-3 beeps

Comment: I've never updated firmware.  By 6 versions, you mean I should have Ver. 7.0+ .  Note that the motherboard itself is discontinued.  Is new firmware likely to work with it?

Comment: From your beep code link, 2 beeps is parity error and 3 beeps is base 64K memory failure.  If I'm wrong about that, I've really missed something.  Also, I keep getting the suggestion that this discussion be moved to chat.  Should we?

Comment: The current firmware you have installed is 1.3.  The current firmware for that motherboard is 1.11.  So its actually 8 firmware revisions out of date.  This is the exact type of problem where you try a firmware upgrade before you do anything.  Additionally the 64k error is more then 5 beeps in total hence the reason I pointed out there is something else going on.

Comment: I finally managed to flash my BIOS.  Now I have version 1.50 2/1/2007.  Booting gives me one set of 4 beeps: Timer not operational - bad motherboard.  That would explain why a memory-tester did not find it.